# AngularJS alert strange behavior

Tags: javascript, angularjs, alert, nw.js

I have a bit strange behavior using alert. Here is the point of my function:

```
 $scope.saveAll = function(exitAfterSave){
      //some logic..      
    var message = "The alert text changes depends on configuration";
    var saveAll = projectService.saveAll(filePrefix, rootPath, project);
    saveAll.then(function() { 
          alert(message);
          if(exitAfterSave === true){
           setTimeOut(function(){ exit(); }, 1000);
          }
    }).catch(function(error){ alert('Save Failed', error) })
}
```

And the exit function is pretty simple

```
function exit() {
var gui = require('nw.gui');
gui.App.quit();
}
```

So what I have here is a save and exit functions (both work), the saveAll() returns a promise. When the promise is resolved, I alert the user according to the resolve/reject.
When the save is successful, the alert displays some weird window like icon instead of my message (see attached image). What can it be? I can't figure it out.
Note: this happening on a specific machine, and not on my dev computer.

[image: This is the error]

Comment: a minimal example which can recreate the issue in code snippet here can help us resolve this.

Comment: I can't recreate this on my computer, this happening on a client's computer, consistently.

Comment: is there an error in console? what is the operating system / browser of your client's computer? is this happening on all browsers?

Comment: No errors in console. The client runs the app using node webkit. Windows 10 64 bit. There is no option to run this app in a browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This computer has some problems with native popup boxes. Alert, prompt and confirm does not displayed properly. I ended up replacing it with third party pop up boxes (alertify) and it worked fine. I don't know why this happens, This is just a bypass and not a full solution, but it works.